# Convert date from an unknown factory type

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I had date values in a column like this

```
      2014-08-14
```

it turned into a column with this value

```
      1407992400
```

when I do a class on that column it return type factor, now i am not sure how to put it back together like how it was before, yyyy-mm-dd format ?

```
    dput(date1)
    structure(c(26L, 14L, 12L, 1L, 20L, 19L), .Label = c("1406869200", 
    "1406955600", "1407042000", "1407128400", "1407214800", "1407301200", 
    "1407387600", "1407474000", "1407560400", "1407646800", "1407733200", 
    "1407819600", "1407906000", "1407992400", "1408078800", "1408165200", 
    "1408251600", "1408338000", "1408424400", "1408510800", "1408597200", 
    "1408683600", "1408770000", "1408856400", "1408942800", "1409029200", 
    "1409115600", "1409202000", "1409288400", "1409374800"), class = 
    "factor")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it probably wasn't a Date-classed object, because those are integer dates offset from 1970, so its probably the result of accidentally unclass()-ing a POSIXct-object.

```
> as.POSIXct(1407992400, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2014-08-13 22:00:00 PDT"
```

Through the magic of R timezone manipulations, you get back your original date:

```
 as.Date(as.POSIXct(1407992400, origin="1970-01-01"))
[1] "2014-08-14"
```

The format() function gives the UCT/UTC version of that time aswell:

```
> format(as.POSIXct(1407992400, origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2014-08-13"
```

Comment: I think we have to be careful with the time zone.

Comment: Hey, those of us on Left Coast of the Other Side of the Pond may still have a little daylight tonight.

Comment: @BondedDust, and Pascal, i tired that and i get an error saying `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Oooops needed to either use the correct arguments for `as.POSIXlt.character` which are different than for `as.POSIXct.numeric` or wrap `as.numeric(as.character(.))` around it

Comment: @Pascal - `as.numeric(as.character(date1))` I think you mean.

Comment: This is an alternat plan for de-factorization: `date1 <- as.numeric(levels(date1))`

Comment: @thelatemail But you only get 6 values.

Comment: @Pascal - `length(date1)` **is** `6`

Comment: @BondedDust - why would you want to use the `levels` of the factor as the data?

Comment: Did I get it wrong? There are two ways R-FAQ-sanctioned ways to convert factors to character: `as.numeric(as.character(f))` or `as.numeric(levels(f))[as.integer(f)]`

Comment: @BondedDust - yep, you missed the `[as.integer(f)]` on your first go.